# Jaspersoft studio: UTF-8 encoding issue

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I am using Jaspersoft Studio final version (v6.1.1). I have designed my report and it contains Turkish characters. When exporting the report from Studio as PDF Turkish characters are not shown although I've set the Studio workspace encoding to UTF-8. Also I have embed the jrxml report file in my JSF app and export the report, the result is the same.

Do I have to configure something more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. In the Jaspersoft Studio IDE, change encoding to UTF-8 in Window/Prefrences/General/Workspace. Afterwards click any field, parameter, or text in the IDE and from the Properties/Advanced menu select PDF/PDF Encoding. I hope it will help.

Comment: Hello, i am having the same issue for Turkish characters.  I was looking to your answer but there is no UTF-8 encoding selection in the PDF Encoding Selection box.. Have any suggestions ?

Comment: Hello, I am using Jaspersoft Studio 6.4.3 final version. In the "Advanced" option of any field there is "PDF/PDF Encoding" menu. From there you can choose any encoding regarding your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I have posted another solution, i hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

I think i have found an easier and more general solution. Instead of changing encoding of every field, you can do it using java coding from your web application`s controller. Below is my solution, i hope it helps a bit. Just put the font to your webapp folder. And change the encoding programatically. BTW greetings from turkey :)

```
    JRDesignStyle jrDesignStyle = new JRDesignStyle();
    /*Set the Encoding to UTF-8 for pdf and embed font to arial*/
    jrDesignStyle.setDefault(true);
    String fontPath = req.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/jasper/arial.ttf");
    jrDesignStyle.setPdfFontName(fontPath);
    jrDesignStyle.setPdfEncoding("Identity-H");
    jrDesignStyle.setPdfEmbedded(true);
    jasperPrint.addStyle(jrDesignStyle);

    JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
```

Comment: Hey, I come across your answer and it works but after printing first line, the report is blank. Any idea?